# ehcache and logging issue

Tags: java, logging, ehcache

Some days ago I started using ehcache in web app. All was fine, and I do remember that when ehcache was putting something in the cach, or retrieving existing value from cache - it was written in the log files. 
I do not know what was changed since that time, and now ehcache is still working (I checked it attentively, in debug mode too), but without any logging.

What can be the cause of such behaviour?

The list of ehcache & log dependencies in my maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>   
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I can assure that log4j.properties was not changed since that time.

Answer (score 1):

To get put/gets/removes and so on logged, the cache needs to have statistics enabled. You can control this either programmatically or in your ehcache.xml.

Comment: logging options is enabled. statistics option AFAIK is used for ehcache monitor only. but, anyway, it's enabled too.

Comment: Only when statistics are enable, the logging for Cache about misses and hits will actually log. Level for net.sf.ehcache.Cache should be at debug as well.

Comment: yes, net.sf.ehcache=DEBUG is in the log4j.properties, but it does not help

Comment: to add a little detail to this answer, adding statistics="true" in the     <defaultCache eternal="true"  cache entry solved this for me